# SQL Update statement with subquery in the where clause same table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am currently a student and I am trying to tackle a slight problem with SQL. I want to do an update statement on a table based on filtered results from that same table. 
[Here is the table I have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b831H.png)

This is the query I have up to now:

```
UPDATE ComplexityLessons
SET ACADEMYRATIO = '0,896' 
WHERE (
    SELECT c.START, c.DATE, c.ACTIVITY, c.ACADEMY
from ComplexityLessons c
join (
    SELECT b.ACTIVITY, b.START, b.DATE
    FROM ComplexityLessons b
) as b 
on c.ACTIVITY = b.ACTIVITY and c.DATE = b.DATE and c.START = b.START
having COUNT(DISTINCT ACADEMY) = 2)
```

So to summarise I want to update the column "ActivityRatio" only where 2 academies conduct the same activity at the same time. When I use only the subquery I get the academies that perform the same activity at the same time, but I cannot figure out the update statement. 
Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved!

Comment: @jarlh: I am using phpmyadmin, so MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ComplexityLessons SET ACADEMYRATIO = '0,896' 
WHERE ( SELECT c.START, c.DATE, c.ACTIVITY, c.ACADEMY 
        from ComplexityLessons c 
join ( SELECT b.ACTIVITY, b.START, b.DATE 
       FROM ComplexityLessons b ) as b 
on c.ACTIVITY = b.ACTIVITY and c.DATE = b.DATE and c.START = b.START 
having COUNT(DISTINCT ACADEMY) = 2)
```

The where is supposed to have the condition and the sub query should return the ids.
for example

```
UPDATE ComplexityLessons SET ACADEMYRATIO = '0,896'
WHERE <id> in ( SELECT <id> from ComplexityLessons c 
join ( SELECT b.ACTIVITY, b.START, b.DATE 
       FROM ComplexityLessons b ) as b 
on c.ACTIVITY = b.ACTIVITY and c.DATE = b.DATE and c.START = b.START 
having COUNT(DISTINCT ACADEMY) = 2)
```

the  should be the foriegn key between the tables.

Comment: I tried it but it still gives me the error "Operand should contain only one column"

Comment: UPDATE ComplexityLessons SET ACADEMYRATIO = '0,896' WHERE ACTIVITY IN (SELECT c.START, c.DATE, c.ACTIVITY, c.ACADEMY from ComplexityLessons c join ( SELECT b.ACTIVITY, b.START, b.DATE FROM ComplexityLessons b ) as b on c.ACTIVITY = b.ACTIVITY and c.DATE = b.DATE and c.START = b.START having COUNT(DISTINCT ACADEMY) = 2) @Sambi Reddy

Comment: The subquery should return the activity. the query should be: UPDATE ComplexityLessons SET ACADEMYRATIO = '0,896' WHERE ACTIVITY IN (SELECT c.ACTIVITY from ComplexityLessons c join ( SELECT b.ACTIVITY, b.START, b.DATE FROM ComplexityLessons b ) as b on c.ACTIVITY = b.ACTIVITY and c.DATE = b.DATE and c.START = b.START having COUNT(DISTINCT ACADEMY) = 2)

Comment: This time I got the following error "#1093 - Table 'ComplexityLessons' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data"

Comment: yes, you cannot query and update the tables at same time. use the activity table itself as self inner join and get the activity.